# Is this a floppy disk connector to the power supply?

Tags: connector

[image]Hi, i would like to know if it is correct that the connnector of the image is a floppy disk to power source connector (the one above). I would also like to know what kind of connector is the second one in the image (the one below). It is a connector that comes from the front panel, and i don't know how am i supposed to use it.

Comment: Any chance you could upload a better picture? I'm having a hard time seeing the bottom one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are power connectors: the first one is a mini-peripheral power connector and is mainly used for floppy disks, card readers and other 3,50" devices. The second one is a peripheral power connector and was used to power hard drives, optical drives, and other internal devices; though it has been almost substituted by the SATA power cable.

The one in your picture looks like is missing the yellow +12V cable and one of the black cables, so it is most probably a cable to power a fan, a display, or other devices that only need +5v power. Furthermore, looks like it has one pin from the male connector stuck on, so it will be useless unless you can remove that with needle-nose pliers.

You can see pictures of the most used internal power connectors in the following page: [All about the various PC power supply cables and connectors](http://www.playtool.com/pages/psuconnectors/connectors.html). I'm adding also a picture with pinouts for both connectors:

[image: Power connectors pinout]

Answer (score 1):

What you are holding looks like what I remember as a floppy disk power connector yes (although I haven't seen one in at least a decade).

The other one I do not recognize, so I would suspect that it something purpose-made for the harddrive-case combination and its front panel outside of the ATX standard.